# APT: Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 10.158.100.1 8080]

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates, proxy

My internet connection is behind a proxy, which I've configured in the GUI, in the environment variables, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

I receive this error every time I attempt to execute `sudo apt update`:

```
Err:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x bionic InRelease                                            
Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 10.158.100.1 8080]
Err:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease`
```

Does this mean that the proxy is being used elsewhere and is therefore unavailable, or why would I be receiving this error?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem,
The solution:

```
sudo vi /etc/environment

http_proxy="http://my.proxyserver.net:8080/" https_proxy="http://my.proxyserver.net:8080/" ftp_proxy="http://my.proxyserver.net:8080/"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1,::1
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your proxy is fine? Please start debugging with thw following check:

```
curl -x http://yourProxyIp:portNumber -Lk https://askubuntu.com
```

Checking individual web resources, like archive.ubuntu.com, is recommended as well. If the proxy works, please check the settings of your proxy for apt in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` directory. It can look like this:

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90curtin-aptproxy
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://192.168.100.10:8080";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://192.168.100.10:8080";
```

Comment: Curl works, and delivers the HTML of the called website. My browser is also able to retrieve webpages fine.

Comment: This is the content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d`:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://USER:PASS@10.158.100.1:8080";`
`Acquire::https::Proxy "https://USER:PASS@10.158.100.1:8080";`